# Compiler Error with missing deffinative

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am a beginning application developer, experiencing the following error from an ASP.NET page on our application. I have tried narrowing it down, still having issues solving this error:

Compiler Error Message: **CS1061: 'load_requestClass' does not contain a definition for 'Admin_MyLoadRequestListing' and no extension method 'Admin_MyLoadRequestListing' accepting a first argument of type '`load_requestClass`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Source Error:

```
Line 28:         private void BindGridView()
Line 29:         {
Line 30:             gdvNewsListing.DataSource = objLoadRequest.Admin_MyLoadRequestListing(txtSearchBox.Value.Trim().Replace("'", "''"), 0);
Line 31:             gdvNewsListing.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(configclass.adminPageSize);
Line 32:             gdvNewsListing.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your object `objLoadRequest` of type `load_requestClass` doesn't have a method named `Admin_MyLoadRequestListing`. Check the `load_requestClass` whether you have this method.

Maybe you didn't add `using load_requestClass;` or it's namespace. Because current namespace may not have visibility to this class.